# How can I transfer the text of an item in a Listview to a new page through the ViewModel?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a listview populated with user-created items. When an item is tapped, it takes the user to a new page that changes its labels based on the name of the item through the Viewmodel.

I am new to data binding, and am trying to teach myself how to do it, but the online documentation is very lacking.

I am successful in getting the information to the ViewModel through a SelectedItem binding, however, it does not transfer to the next page.

ViewModel:

```
public ClassListModel classDetails;
public string className; //Bound to Label in next page
public ClassListModel ClassDetails //Bound to SelectedItem in first page
        {
            get
            {
                return classDetails;
            }            
            set {
                if (classDetails == value)
                { return; }

                else {
                    classDetails = value;
                    className = classDetails.Name;
                    OnPropertyChanged("ClassDetails");
                }
            }
        }
```

The label is blank, any suggestions?

Comment: Could you show your ItemSelected method which you click and open a new page ?Do you pass the select data to the new page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set item values to new ViewModel before redirecting the page or you can use existing ViewModel and bind as BindingContext of the new page.

On new page you will have ViewModel populated with values.

```
public void ItemSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var item = (MyListViewItem) sender;
    var nextPage = new NextPage
    {
        BindingContext = new NextPageViewModel
        {
            Label = item.Label,
            ...
        }
    };

    await Navigation.PushAsync(nextPage);
}
```